# How do I disable MSVC warnings from headers included with quotes instead of angle brackets when using /analyze?

Tags: visual-c++

I am trying to add the `/analyze` flag to `cl`.

I am getting a warnings from external headers I `#include "..."`, even though I am using `/analyze:external-` and `/external:I ...`.

What am I doing wrong?

Example project:

[image: external dir with external.h inside, plus main.cpp at the top level]

*main.cpp*

```cpp
#include "external.h"
// #include <external.h>  <- hides external's warnings

int main() {
  int shadowed = 0;
  { float shadowed = 0; }

  return 0;
}
```

*external.h*

```cpp
void something() {
  int external_shadowed = 0;
  { float external_shadowed = 0; }
}
```

I run this command from the VS developer prompt:

`cl /EHsc /analyze /analyze:external- /I include /external:I external /external:W0 main.cpp`

And I proceed to get warnings from both files.

Comment: Removing the "optional space" after the /external:I does not work. There are also no spaces in the path name, if that matters.

Comment: FWIW, I suspected that the issue is with you trying to exclude project's child folder. I can't suppress warnings on the external include either. Also, if I specify a complete path in `<>`, I see warnings even with `/external:anglebrackets`. Looks like where and how the header was found matters.

Comment: @VladFeinstein you are right about the angle brackets not fixing it, I was mistaken. However moving the external folder up a directory still does not change things for me.

Comment: Actually, it seems like `<>` *does* do the trick. The "uninitialized value" warning just shows up without `/analyze` anyways, which was confusing me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems MSVC only considers `/external:I` directories to actually be external if they are included with `<>` instead of `""`. This is not documented anywhere, and I would consider it a bug with the compiler. Third-party libraries should not necessarily always be included with `<>`.

More info and possibly updates in the future here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/analyze:external--and-external:I-flags/1688240

I have not tested myself, but [according to Hwi-sung Im [MSFT]](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/analyze:external--and-external:I-flags/1688240#T-N1689542), `<>` and `""` now act the same w.r.t `/external:I` in Visual Studio 2022 17.0.

Answer (score 0):

There may be an additional reason why `/analyze:external-` and `/external:I` have no effect: you check CA result right after project load.
Possibly a bug, but starting CA manually from MSVC menu or on build
*Configuration -> Code Analysis -> General -> Enable Code Analysis on Build*
for me is different from starting output and actually uses exclude rules.